# Sum Values from a for

Tags: jquery, sum

I need to sum the values of a variable (`pago_copago`), but don't know how to do it, because I do the code like this:

```
var resultado = parseFloat(pago_copago) + parseFloat(pago_copago)+1;
```

The problem is that it adds 1 to the result and what I mean to do is to sum `pago_copago` in the next position.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {

    var total_copago = copago * 12.50;
    var pago_copago = jsonResponse[i]["fields"]["medicamento_precio"] - total_copago;

    var resultado = parseFloat(pago_copago) + parseFloat(pago_copago);

    $("#resultTables").append('<tr><td style="text-align: center" id="{{medicamentos.medicamentos_nombre}}" >' + jsonResponse[i]["fields"]["medicamento_nombre"] + '</td>' + '' +
        '<td style="text-align: center" id="{{medicamentos.medicamentos_precio}}" >' + "$" + jsonResponse[i]["fields"]["medicamento_precio"] + '</td>' + '<td style="text-align: center" >' + "$" + pago_copago + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<input type="checkbox" id="{{medicamentos.medicamentos_status}}" >' + '</td></tr>');
}
},
```

Comment: Is that really supposed to be ```parseFloat(pago_copago) + parseFloat(pago_copago)```? That is just doubling it, not summing it.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the declaration `var resultado` out. This will remove resetting its value everytime.

Use `resultado +=` to add for each iteration.

```
var resultado = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {
    var total_copago= copago * 12.50;
    var pago_copago = jsonResponse[i]["fields"]["medicamento_precio"] - total_copago;

    resultado += parseFloat(pago_copago);//whatever you want to add here

    ...
}
```